# Android - open dialog when image is clicked

Tags: android, android-imageview, android-dialog

I'm trying to open a dialog window when an ImageView is clicked.
When the image is clicked I get the following error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ListView.setAdapter(android.widget.ListAdapter)' on a null object reference
                                                                                 at il.ac.shenkar.david.todolistex2.InviteMember.onPersonIconClick(InviteMember.java:182)
```

But all objects are initialized.

I have a separate layout for the dialog that I wish to open:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="200dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:id="@+id/invitememberLayout3">

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/emplist_listView"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
</LinearLayout>
```

I instantiate the ImageView as follows:

```
    person_img = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.person_icon);
    person_img.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            onPersonIconClick(v);
        }
    });
```

**This is the onPersonIconClick method:**

```
public void onPersonIconClick (View view)
{
    final Dialog d = new Dialog(InviteMember.this);
    d.setTitle("Employee List");
    d.setContentView(R.layout.employeelist);
    all_emp_list = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.emplist_listView);
    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, emp_List);
    all_emp_list.setAdapter(adapter);
    all_emp_list.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    d.show();
}
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

> What am I doing wrong here?

`(ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.emplist_listView);`

That line is usually called on a view that contains a listview. The view that you pass to `onPersonIconClick()` is not a view that contains a listview. It is instead the imageview that you click on and get a reference to in

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    onPersonIconClick(v);
}
```

So basically you're calling `findViewById(R.id.emplist_listView);` on your imageview.

You probably want to keep a 'global' reference to your listview so that you don't have to re-initialize it in your separate method.

Comment: What do you mean by 'global' reference?

Comment: @DavidFaiz an instance of the listview that you define in the top level scope of the activity so you can use inside the onclick method

Answer (score 1):

Try this...

You need to inflate the view that you want for your dialog. and get the reference of your listview from that inflated view.

If you don't get the reference from their inflated view or view is not found, then it give you **NullPointerException**.

```
final Dialog d = new Dialog(InviteMember.this);
        d.setTitle("Employee List");
        View dialogView = LayoutInflater.from(InviteMember.this).inflate(R.layout.employeelist, null);
        d.setContentView(dialogView);
        all_emp_list = (ListView) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.emplist_listView);
        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, emp_List);
        all_emp_list.setAdapter(adapter);
        all_emp_list.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        d.show();
```

Comment: Why? What is different and why?

Comment: Because view must find the reference from their Layout.

Comment: Explain it in the answer. don't just dump code without saying anything about it

Comment: Issue still exits, getting NULL reference on:
"all_emp_list.setAdapter(adapter);"

Comment: I have checked it, its working fine on my side. Try  clean and rebuild the project and let me know. If the exception persists then let me know the exception.

Answer (score 0):

Went in a more traditional way, and placed all the logic in the AlertDialog creation:

```
    person_img = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.person_icon);
    person_img.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(InviteMember.this);
            dialog.setContentView(R.layout.employeelist);
            dialog.setTitle("Employee List");
            all_emp_list = (ListView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.emplist_listView);
            adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(InviteMember.this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, emp_List);
            all_emp_list.setAdapter(adapter);
            dialog.show();
        }
    });
```